# How to enable concertina effect?

Tags: unity, launcher

The launcher in Ubuntu 11.10 has no concertina effect like it had in Ubuntu 11.04. Does anyone know how to enable this function?

Answer (score 1):

This is called an [accordion effect](http://design.canonical.com/2010/06/introduction-to-unity-launcher/), it is still present in Unity in 11.10. If you move the mouse over the launcher the effect disappears, all icons expand, and you need to scroll up and down to see them.